# how to check mongodb gear space in openshift

Tags: mongodb, openshift

I have a scaled openshift app that use 1 gear for tomcat7 and 1 gear for mongodb. Is there any way I can check how much space left for the mongodb gear. It supposed to provice 1 GB storage but when my db size reaches around 200M, it'll stop saving new data.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic , not about programming but administration. Try [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/) or otherwise in the vendor documentation or ask them.

Comment: openshift tells us to use stackoverflow since for supports since their developers monitor questions with "openshift" tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `rhc app show <appname> --gears quota` to view how much storage is used on each gear.  You can also ssh to your mongodb gear and see what is taking up so much space, but it's probably this: https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202186004-Apparent-excessive-disk-usage-by-MongoDB

Answer (score 1):

My guess at your problem is the way in which mongodb grabs space when it needs to expand. I think, but not sure of the exact algorithm, that it will grab twice as much space as it just asked for. So example, once it needs to expand past 400, it will ask for an additional 800, giving you 1.2 gigs.

To see  how much disc space your are using you can run this command:

rhc app show {appname} --gears quota

Comment: Tried the command you mentioned. It's saying mongodb gear is using 0.8GB. But, in the mongodb stats, the storageSize is only 207MB. No idea what the extra space used for in the gear.

Comment: I am not sure either - sorry. Though it may be related to the issue I highlighted above